# Why does ListBox not display objects correctly?

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a listbox and a class.
The class is called CTS_Warnings_List
And the listbox is called lbpropWarningFacList

Here is the class:

```
Public Class CTS_Warnings_List
Public _Warning As String
Public _WarnID As Integer


Public Property Warning() As String
    Get
        Return _Warning
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Warning = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property WarnID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _WarnID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _WarnID = value
    End Set
End Property


Sub New(ByVal Warning As String, ByVal WarnID As Integer)
    Me.Warning = Warning
    Me.WarnID = WarnID
End Sub

End Class
```

So now I want to add a new item to the listbox. So I tried this:

```
Dim llist As New CTS_Warnings_List("K", 8)
    lbpropWarningFacList.Items.Add(llist)
```

I also tried this:

```
lbpropWarningFacList.Items.Add(New CTS_Warnings_List("K", 8))
```

When I run the app and add these to the listbox, in each case I get this displayed in the listbox:

**NameOfApplication.NameOfClass**

as the display in the listbox.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You should override the `ToString` method in your class.

Answer (score 3):

Listboxes only knows how to display strings.
Therefor, when you add an item of any type to the listbox, it displays the value it gets by calling the items `ToString()` method.

You should override the `ToString()` method or simply enter items as strings in the first place.

In your case, add this to your class:

```
Public overrides function ToString() as string
    return Me.Warning & " " & Me.WarnID.ToString()
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You are sending a CTS_Warnings_List object to a listbox.  How does the listbox know what to do with that object?  It **doesn't** know what to do with that object.  If you want to send the properties of the object to the listbox, then you have to do something like:

```
lbpropWarningFacList.Items.Add(llist._WarnID & ": " & llist.Warning)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses. But I found that if I add

```
NameOfListBox.DisplayMemeber = "PropertyOfClass"
NameOfListBox.ValueMember = "PropertyOfClass"
```

By just adding this it now shows the correct data in the listbox.